# how to search a file order output in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a text file called "file.txt" with an output like below

```
Ethernet4
vEthernet
Ethernet
Ethernet
Public
```

Is there any methord in powershell to check , whether the name vEthernet is first in order of the output file ?

Comment: *"Is there any methord in powershell..."* Powershell is a complete programming language, so there most certainly is. Have you tried anything or did you just come to let other people do your job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the first element of an array you can use the brackets with 0 `[0]` like that :

```
$myArray = @('Ethernet4', 'vEthernet', 'Ethernet', 'Ethernet', 'Public')
$myArray[0]
```

so if you want to test the first element, you can use a if :

```
if($myArray[0] -eq 'vEthernet') {
    Write-Host 'YES'
} else {
    Write-Host 'NO'
}
```

---

Better answer for your particular problem :

Since your input comes from a file, if you need to read only the first line and not more :

```
$result = Get-Content -Path '.\file.txt' -TotalCount 1

if($result -eq 'vEthernet') {
    Write-Host 'YES'
} else {
    Write-Host 'NO'
}
```